# how to make xsendfile to work in python/django

Tags: python, django

i am using windows and python. how to install mod_xsendfile.c file for django. I mean what command to write to install this to make it accessible

Comment: Are you asking how to compile and install an apache module?

Comment: yes how to make xsendfile to work

Comment: You can not install it for `Django`, you should install it for `apache` or `nginx`. if you want to use `xampp`, looks at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3523822/538284), also look at [this](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile) django extension for that.

Comment: i want to use this to make my file to be able to download. @OmidRaha

Comment: @OmidRaha `I still recommend you build yourself from the source. That way you can be sure the binary isn't tampered with, not even by me` i don't understand this