# x-sendfile activation in apache2

Tags: php, apache2, x-sendfile

i have microsoft windows server iis 7 and i have installed apache2 on it 
the x-sendfile plugin is installed on apache but when i test it by following code

```
if (in_array('mod_xsendfile', $modules)) {
// If mod_xsendfile is loaded, use X-Sendfile to deliver.. (optional: I have this as failover to use PHP readfile() if mod_xsendfile is unavailable)
header ('X-Sendfile: ' . $pathToFile);
header ('Content-Type: ' . $documentMIME);
header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $actualFilename . '"');
exit;}
```

nothing happen !!!
what's the problem ?

Comment: How is `$modules` populated? You can see if the mod_xsendfile is loaded via phpinfo(); - it's listed under "Loaded modules" if it's present. Have you enabled the x-sendfile in the httpd.conf? `LoadModule xsendfile_module modules/mod_xsendfile.so` and `<IfModule xsendfile_module>
 XSendFile on
</IfModule>` Both need to be present?

Comment: thanks , problem solved !!! xD

Answer (score 1):

This has already been somewhat answered here by the author of mod_xsendfile himself:
[mod_xsendfile for Win x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078804/mod-xsendfile-for-win-x64)

I'm assuming you are on Windows 64 bit with Windows 7. He stated there was no build for that although others in that thread got it working. I would read through their comments/replies. Install and make sure the httpd file is modified to load it correctly. Good luck.